# Android- Populate custom Views in GridView

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview, android-custom-view

I'm developing an Android Application where I need to create a custom view and have to populate that view repeatedly in Grid View .

Here is my code snippets for creating the view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layoutContent"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/navigationtextheaderbg">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The Gridview Adapter is given below,

```
class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

  Context c;
  int[] imageResources;
 String[] arrayTexts;

    GridViewAdapter(Context x,int[] imageResourses, String[] array )
    {
        this.c=x;
        this.imageResources=imageResourses;
        this.arrayTexts=array;
    } 



    @Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arrayTexts.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub




    View v=View.inflate(c,R.layout.grid,null);
    TextView tv1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    ImageView iv1=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    tv1.setText(arrayTexts[position]);

    iv1.setBackgroundResource(imageResources[position]);



    return v;
}

}
```

I'm calling this Adapter using the following code snippets,

```
GridView gridView=new GridView(MainActivity.this);
                                gridView.setNumColumns(4);

                                GridViewAdapter adapter=new GridViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,imageresources,arr1);

                                gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

here **imageresourses & arr1** is an array of **Images and string** respectively .

```
int[] imageresources= new int[]{R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher};
    String[] arr1={"Ima","hello","yes","no"};
```

Comment: what is the issue? error? please post the log cat then.

Comment: I didn't face the issue . I'm in turmoil on how to create a populate a custom view in Gridview.

Comment: just Google it (Custom GridView android) and you will find lots of code!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you even set the GridView as contentView?

```
setContentView(gridView);
```

And you should set the XML file you have above as contentview in your adapter class.

```
View v=View.inflate(c,R.layout.grid,null);
```

Comment: I could add the Grid view contents . But I need to add Custom Views in GridView.

Comment: Is the XML file above R.layout.grid?